# Relative Jacobian condition

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry

This question is really elementary.

Where can I learn about the Jacobian condition not over a field?

I think I heard once that there's a Jacobian condition even for $f: X \rightarrow Y$. I'm not really sure what that would be, and what it would imply if it's satisfied, but I'd like some good references so I can learn.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you want a generalization of the Jacobian criteria  for the smoothness of, say, a variety to the case of a morphism of schemes?  If so, then the
 [Néron Models](http://books.google.com/books?id=4kgfAQAAIAAJ&q=N%C3%A9ron+models&dq=N%C3%A9ron+models&hl=en&ei=1EmqTMEHxoCUB92TyaUN&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA)
 book has a nice discussion of this in the section on smoothness.

Comment: @BCnrd: Thanks for pointing this out.  Edited to make my meaning more clear.